# Criteria Query for count

Tags: jpa, criteriaquery

```
SELECT count(d.*)
FROM (
    SELECT s.id
        ,avg(e.marks)
    FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN Exam e ON s.id = e.student_id
    GROUP BY s.id
    ) d
```

How to represent this for JPA Criteria query to get no of records

Answer (score 0):

Looks this is not possible in Criteria Query going ahead with Database view for same